# What was the reason for Andy's absence in The Office

Tags: character, production, the-office

A large portion of the current season (I think it's season 9), Andy (Ed Helms) was sailing a boat to the Bahamas. He was out of the show for a number of episodes (around 8) which is unusual for The Office.

What was the reason for Ed Helms' absence from the show?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ed Helms took time off to shoot Hangover 3.

> The reason for his absence, which is explained on the show as Andy and his brother taking a boat trip to find themselves, is that the actor has been hard at work on some film projects including “The Hangover Part III.”

[Source](http://cartermatt.com/45401/nbcs-the-office-season-9-spoilers-more-on-ed-helms-return-documentary-crew/)

Or even

> Ed Helms...has been noticeably absent now for weeks while off shooting The Hangover 3;

[Source](http://www.grantland.com/blog/hollywood-prospectus/post/_/id/66608/nbc-comedy-recap-two-shows-nearing-the-end-give-us-what-we-want-and-what-we-desperately-dont-want)